# MYSQL ERROR: unknown table `airports`

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT `aalv_test`.`aircraft`.*, `aalv_test`.`airports`.*, `aalv_test`.`bids`.* 
FROM `bids` 
LEFT JOIN `aalv_test`.`pilots` ON `bids`.`pid` = `pilots`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `aalv_test`.`schedules` ON `bids`.`fid` = `schedules`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `aalv_test`.`aircraft` ON `schedules`.`aircraft` = `aircraft`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `aalv_test`.`airports` AS `arr` ON `schedules`.`arricao` = `arr`.`icao`
LEFT JOIN `aalv_test`.`airports` AS `dep` ON `schedules`.`depicao` = `dep`.`icao` 
WHERE `pilots`.`id` = 419
```

However,
MYSQL returns error #1051 - Table `airports` does not exist.
I don't know what the issue is and Google hasn't helped. Any ideas? Also, if I only use one alias, I only get one airport but I need both. And the data is only in the table `airports` which according to this query, does not exist. Also, if I try throwing an AS section in the SELECT clause, I get error 1064: syntax error near AS.

EDIT: Database name is `aalv_test`, the .* at the end specifies to use all fields in the table, and the middle part is the table name, yes I am chaining fields.

Comment: You seem to have a period after `airports`.  Remove the period after the field name.

Comment: Now, it seems that you are chaining fields.  You can't have `aalv_test.aircraft.*`.  You need to change it to `aalv_test.*` or `aalv_test.aircraft`.

Comment: So then how do I get all fields of the table? Do I have to list each one individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*, arr.*, dep.*, b.* 
FROM bids AS b 
LEFT JOIN aalv_test.pilots AS p ON b.pid = p.id 
LEFT JOIN aalv_test.schedules AS s ON b.fid = s.id
LEFT JOIN aalv_test.aircraft AS a ON s.aircraft = a.id 
LEFT JOIN aalv_test.airports AS arr ON s.arricao = arr.icao
LEFT JOIN aalv_test.airports AS dep ON s.depicao = dep.icao 
WHERE p.id = 419;
```